# A RegEx for: {0}

Tags: javascript, regex

I feel like an idiot for asking this but what would a regular expression be to match the literal string: {0}

This would be used in JavaScript with the string object's replace function. I've tried several things and nothing seems to work.

Thanks, 
Frank

Comment: Maybe it's a matter of escaping the curly braces?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
"{0}".match(/\{0\}/)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you bdonlan.

Your post informed me that it wasn't my regEx but my use of the replace function.

I was trying:

```
MyString.replace(/\{0\}/, "test");
```

And it should have been:

```
 MyString = MyString.replace(/\{0\}/, "test");
```

Again, thank you!